# Getting java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException while invoking a method on remote object

Tags: java, rmi

I know such kind of questions have been asked before.But my problem is little different.
I have 2 services , A and B.A uses methods of B via RMI.
B exports itself via below 3 statments:-

```
Remote stub = UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject( rs, port,socketFactory,socketFactory);
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry( port,socketFactory,socketFactory  );
registry.rebind( serviceBindName, stub );
```

where rs is the remote object implementation.

Now A looks up B via below 2 statements :-

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry( BsIP, BsRMIPort);
RemoteServiceRegistry rs = ( RemoteServiceRegistry ) registry.lookup( serviceBindName);
```

Now everything works smoothly.A obtains stub from B via lookup and caches it for all subsequent requests.
But problems starts when i restart B.I have mechanism via which whenever B restarts i clear the cache and perform a fresh lookup of B in A.But somehow its not working and throws exceptions in both A and B.

I am clueless about this . Please help.Do let me know if you need more information.

Exception in A

```
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
        at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
```

Exception in B ( after adding a property to JVM ,-Djava.rmi.server.logCalls=true)

```
FINE: RMI TCP Connection(10)-192.168.50.243: [192.168.50.243] exception:
java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:135)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: One note . The problem disappears after restarting A.But that solution is not acceptable to me.Somewhere something is wrong.Please help in diagnosing this.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that the remote stub is 'stale', i.e. refers to an object that is no longer exported from the JVM the stub came from. When you get this exception you must re-acquire the stub via the same means you got it in the first place:

- if via a `lookup()`, redo the lookup.
- if via a remote method call of your own, redo it, and note that that in turn can fail with the same exception, and so on recursively.

> .I have mechanism via which whenever B restarts i clear the cache and perform a fresh lookup of B in A

Clearly that mechanism isn't working or isn't being invoked.

NB You should always store the result of `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` in a static variable, to prevent the Registry from being garbage-collected.

Comment: Hi EJP , Thanks for your response.I checked it by putting in loggers , and i found that on B's restart ,  A does fresh RMI lookup via the way i mentioned in the  code above.Is there any other issue you suspect ?

Comment: Are you getting this on the lookup itself? or when calling a remote method on the acquired stub?

Comment: On calling remote method on acquired stub.

Comment: Also , if registry in B is getting GCed then how come everything works smoothly after restarting A ?

Comment: Then you're clearly looking at a stale registry with stale stubs in it. So the restart/re-export/rebind process in B isn't working somehow.

Comment: Is there any issue in the 3 statements above which i am issuing to export the object ? I doubt there is any issue in that because the strange part is that on restart of A , everything works fine.I am not even touching B.

Comment: Actually there is. If you create a Registry with a client socket factory, you must use the same client socket factory in getRegistry().

Comment: Sorry EJP , but i did not get you.What do you mean by using same socketFactory in both createRegistry() and getRegistry() . Both are happening in different JVM. And also as i said , the issue gets resolved on restart of A.So is there some stale object in A's JVM which gets cleared on restart of A ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56251/discussion-between-vimal-jain-and-ejp).

Comment: 'Same socket factory' seems clear enough to me, but to spell it out, an instance of the same client socket factory class used in `createRegistry()` must also be supplied to `getRegistry().`